# Collect function with iterator issue

Tags: iterators, factorization

I've got the following code for the first few terms of an expansion. I want to collect the terms in increasing powers of `(s/r)` but using an iterator. The code is as follows:

```
formula=1-n x + 1/2 n (n+1) x^2-1/6 n (n+1 ) (n+2) x^3 /. {x->((s/r)^2-2 (s/r) Cos[θ]),
        n->1/2};
Expand[%];
Collect[%,{(s/r),(s/r)^2,(s/r)^3,(s/r)^4}]
```

The output is what I want but how would I do this using a counter or iterator? So something like

```
Collect[%, {(s/r)^i,{i,0,n}}]
```

But obviously not that because it doesn't work!

Comment: Could you just preinitialize your list of factors? E.g. `Collect[Expand[formula], Table[(s/r)^i, {i, 5}]]`

Comment: Excellent job. I had tried something almost the same but your has worked a treat! If you want to write it as an answer I shall kindly accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can pre-initialize our list of factors with `Table`:

`Collect[Expand[formula], Table[(s/r)^i, {i, 5}]]`

should get the job done.

Or, as Bob Hanlon notes, `Power` is `Listable` so we can do:

```
Collect[Expand[formula], (s/r)^Range[5]]
```

Comment: Ah very nice. Didn't know `Power` was `Listable`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Collect`, you can use `PolynomialReduce`

```
Flatten@PolynomialReduce[formula, Table[(s/r)^i, {i, n /. n -> 5}], {s, r}][[2]]
```